# JSON Schema - allow null with regex pattern

Tags: json, jsonschema

Would like to allow null on an optional date property where the date format is validated with a regex expression. Is this even possible?

```
"dateOfRetirement": {
  "description": "Optional. Format: yyyy-MM-dd.",
  "type": ["string", "null"],
  "pattern": "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the regular syntax for that you have to add a condition to your regex.

Your regex will get (assuming your regex syntax has no error!):

```
^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}|null)$
```

**Steps done:**

- incapsulate the normal regex with brackets (`()`)
- add an *or*-operator to the regex (`|`)
- add the second validation for `null` to the regex after the or-operator

In the end the regex will allow a-valid-date-format or `null` as text.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I updated the JSON as well to change: "dateOfRetirement" : "" to: "dateOfRetirement" : null,

Comment: that is wrong. The schema in the question is ok, if the value is `null` the `pattern` keyword will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work when "column": null.

It will only account for "column": "null" in regex